# Generate HTML form from XSD file

Tags: php, html, xml, xsd, generated

Hi I want to generate an HTML form according to this XSD file, I know there are way with Javascript but I want with PHP if is possiblee.

I have a XSD file as follows:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://example.com/irm" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://example.com/irm">
<xs:element name="GetOrderInfo">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="getOrderInfoRequest" type="tns:getOrderInfoRequest"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="getOrderInfoRequest">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="OrderID" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AgentID" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="GetOrderInfoResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetOrderInfoResult" type="tns:getOrderInfoResponse"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="getOrderInfoResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Installments" type="tns:ArrayOfInstallment"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CorrelationID" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Status" type="tns:Status"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PolicyInPDF" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="OrderStatus" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="BMCoefficient" type="xs:float"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="GrossWrittenPremium" type="xs:decimal"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="HasGreenCard" type="xs:boolean"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="GreenCardStartDate" type="xs:dateTime"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Any suggestions? I'm thinking about something like reading the XSD file with PHP and generate the HTML form and after is generated to send back to the server. Is it possibe? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you share how you would do it with javascript, it's perhaps more clear what you're trying to achieve.